# Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: spring, spring-saml

Thanks Vladimir. After having included my second ADFS configuration and tried to access the same under the metadata page, I got the following exception in the app server console:

```
Error retrieving metadata from //<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.Su
nCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:23
6)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:398)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:246)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:137
)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1351)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 54 more
- Next refresh cycle for metadata provider '//<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml' will occur on
'2014-09-23T11:58:38.338Z' ('2014-09-23T07:58:38.338-04:00' local time)
- Metadata provider failed to properly initialize, fail-fast=true, halting
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error retrie
ving metadata from //<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:23
6)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:398)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:246)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:137
)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error retrieving metadata from //<adfs_server2>/Fed
erationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.
certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1351)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target....
```

I do added the corresponding FederatedMetadata.xml file in the classpath as well.

My Configuration in securityContext.xml file looks like this:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/services/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
<!-- URL containing the metadata -->
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.lang.String">://<adfs_server1>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
<constructor-arg>
<value type="int">5000</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/capital/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
<!-- URL containing the metadata -->
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.lang.String">://<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
<constructor-arg>
<value type="int">5000</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system complains that it's unable to verify the certificate presented by the HTTPS endpoint of your ADFS. You can find details on how to configure trust for such endpoints in the [Spring SAML manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-https), see chapter 7.2, section HTTP-based metadata provider with SSL, it says:

> By default, loading of metadata using the HTTP-based provider over
>   HTTPS performs trust verification configured in your JDK. In case
>   you'd like to use certificates in your keyStore, add the following
>   bean which changes the socketFactory used by the HTTP Client:
>
> ```
>   <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer"/>
> ```
>
> The TLSProtocolConfigurer instantiates TLSProtocolSocketFactory and
>   registers is as a default socket factory for https protocol inside the
>   HTTP Client used for metadata loading. The socket factory uses all
>   public certificates present in the keyStore as trust anchors for PKIX
>   validation. The used keys can be constrained with property
>   trustedKeys.

So you should simply import certificates used by the ADFS into your samlKeystore.jks and configure the above mentioned bean. Details on extracting the certificates and importing them can again be found in the manual.

Comment: Should I add the above bean in the securityContext.xml?  Or is there anything else I need to do.  Kindly clarify.

Comment: Yes, add it to securityContext.xml.

Comment: my metadata file has three different X509Certificate elements :(. One cert start with MIIC8..., MIIC9......  Which one should I pick and put it in the .cer file?

Comment: i tried adding one of the token from my metadata.xml file and ran the keytool command. I got keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate.

Comment: You're not supposed to be adding keys from metadata, those are processed automatically. You are supposed to import certificate from the HTTPS endpoint, e.g. https://<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml, or just put http there instead.

Comment: And you can find documentation in http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/security.html#configuration-key-management-public-keys, chapters 8.1.3 and 8.1.4

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thanks for your response.  Could you please me how to import the certificate from HTTPS endpoint. https://adfs.someservice.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Comment: i saw there is tool available. java -jar release/sslextractor-0.9.jar https://adfs.someservice.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederatedMetadata.xml.  Is this the right way to do it. Please clarify.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It contains a step-by-step guide, including commands to execute. Yes, using the SSL extractor is the way mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: yes I did.  Sorry I think am bothering you too much.  i tried my  best but couldnt import the certificate from the existing url (https://adfs.someservice.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml). can u please help me with the command. or else I will ask my client to share the .cer file

Comment: As you can see in the example: "java -jar sslextractor-0.9.jar www.google.com 443", the SSL extractor takes domain and port as arguments, so you should call it with "java -jar sslextractor-0.9.jar adfs.someservice.com 443"

Comment: Worked man.. Thanks a bunch... sorry if I would have bothered you.

Comment: I'm glad you made it work, these certificate things are sometimes pain in the ass and difficult to get right. Please accept the answer once you get the metadata loaded, so the issue gets closed.

Comment: Thats really true buddy.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,  I have posted a new query "Spring SAML Security with Azure ACS Integration Sample".  If you come across any solutions, pls share it with me.  Thanks